# Am I using the stamina skills wrong in Elder Scrolls Blades?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

There are many times when I go to use a stamina skill (and my stamina bar is 100% full) that it just doesn't work. I'll press on the little diamond icon and nothing happens.

I've even made sure the palm of my hand isn't on the screen either. I've noticed this will prevent the skill from being used sometimes.

I've even made sure the skill "fill bar" or “timer” is all the way 100% unlike this shot below:

[image]

I know some skills are based on timing, but I've been able to use them even outside of the timing (granted they don't do anything effective).

This also happens on regular enemies, such as rats and spiders during 1 Star dungeons. So, it can’t be a max stamina thing.

So, the question is, is there a way to get your skills to work every time, or is this just a bug in the game right now?

Answer (score 1):

1. there is a cooldown timer for each skill. after you use a skill you must wait a certain amount of time to use it again. also, some skills used by enemies have a negative effect on your cooldown timers, so you have to wait longer to use them again.
2. do you have enough max stamina to use the skill? some weapons carried by enemies have enchantments that lower your max health/magicka/stamina therefore it is possible that your max stamina(etc.) will be never enough high to use a skill as long as you fighting with that particular enemy.
3. as long as you are holding your "tap" onto a weapon or shield, you cannot use a skill linked to it. for example, as long as you are holding your shield icon (meaning blocking with your shield) you cannot use skills linked to you shield(for example shield bash).

just a few tips, after playing for a month on a daily basis, hope this helps

Comment: I indicated in my question that my stamina is full and that I’m waiting on the timer. Also, I’m not using the shield or weapon while using it

Comment: then 1. and 3. is not useful in this case. the 2nd case could be still true.

Comment: This does happen on normal enemies that do not cast spells, such as rats

Comment: oh it is simple. rats, small spiders, etc. are far from you basically, so hitting them is only possible when they are coming closer to attack you. spells can be still casted however.

Comment: That’s not it, the buttons don’t work 70% of the time

Comment: no idea then. I am playing on an ipad and have not experienced this bug. what is your device?

Comment: I’m using the iPad Pro

Comment: checked again, on an ipad pro too. it seems that there are some skills which need some cooldown time after swinging your weapon/using shield.

these 4 cases will be answer most of the time, which is 70% for you.

wait more, plan your attacks wiser.

Comment: That's not the case. New monster, not using shield. Cooldowns are done, skill is ready to use. doesn't work.